# How to calculate PAM signal power spectrum

Tags: digital-communications, pulse, amplitude-modulation

[image]
How to calculate power spectrum of given signal

Comment: Where did you get stuck solving this for your homework?

Comment: Thanks for asking! :) I was not able to figure out how to express power spectrum in terms of the autocorrelation of the sequence. I was able to solve  it after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the power spectrum can be represented using the autocorrelation of the a_n sequence and the fourier transform of the g(t) pulse. using the given formula in the image. question solved.

[image: page2]
[image: page3]
[image: page1]